# How to concatenate static methods from a Java class object?

Tags: java, clojure

I'm trying to call the randomVector method from the Vec2D class found here http://toxiclibs.org/docs/core/

Here is my code:

```
(def particles (new ArrayList))


(defn add-particle []
  (dotimes [i 100]
    (doto particles
      ;(.add (new Vec2D (random (width)) (random (height))))
      (.add (Vec2D/randomVector))))
```

So far so good but I need to call other methods like scale and add from the same class, I have not idea how to do that in Clojure

Here is how I do it in Java:

```
Vec2D position = Vec2D.randomVector().scale( 60 ).add( canvasCenter );
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I call a java static method in clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5424520/how-can-i-call-a-java-static-method-in-clojure)

Comment: Regarding your edit about chaining methods: use `..` or `->` with `.`. This is a duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821751/how-do-i-create-a-java-like-object-in-clojure-that-uses-builder-pattern/8821948#8821948

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code, java static methods should be called like `(ClassName/methodName arguments)`

```
(defn add-particle []
  (dotimes [i 100]
    (doto particles
      (.add (Vec2D/randomVector)))))
```

For your second question, any way you need to define `canvasCenter` some where.

```
(defn add-particle []
      (dotimes [i 100]
        (doto particles
          (.add (.scale (Vec2D/randomVector) (float 60)) canvasCenter)))
```

Comment: Oh thanks Kugathasan I found the answer on the other post someone point me as duplicate, but I edited the question wonder if you can help me

Comment: @RicardoSancher: Can you please check the answer now?

Comment: Not yet as I'm getting the following error "No matching method found: scale for class toxi.geom.Vec2D" ;)

Comment: @RicardoSanchez, just check, `scale` method accept float value.

Comment: Thanks for your patience but I'm getting this error Invalid number: 60f I even try 60.0f same error

Comment: @RicardoSanchez: use `(float 60.0)`

Comment: @RicardoSanchez, as Ankur said, i have edited the answer, check now

Comment: BOOMBASTIC! now will it be possible to show me an example using -> or .. as A.Webb point out in the comments?